# Application Insights TrackEvent never persisted in Azure

Tags: typescript, azure-application-insights

I am trying to implement the SDK for Node to track custom events in our code base. The service I've written is called from an asynchronous method chain and runs in Azure Functions:

```js
public async handleEvent(event: Event) {
    // Do stuff

    // Then report event
    this.reportEvent(event);
}

private reportEvent(event: Event) {
    if (this._applicationInsightsService) {
        this._applicationInsightsService.reportEvent(event)
        this._context.log("Successfully sent event to application insights")
    } else {
        this._context.log("Could not send metrics to application insights, service is not defined")
    }
}
```

The service itself looks like this:

```js
export class ApplicationInsightsService {

    private _instance: ApplicationInsights

    private constructor(connectionString: string) {
        this._instance = new ApplicationInsights({ 
            config: {
                connectionString: connectionString
            } 
        })
        this._instance.loadAppInsights()
    }

    public static create() {
        if (process.env.APPLICATION_INSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING === undefined) {
            throw new Error("APPLICATION_INSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING undefined, cannot report metrics")
        }
        return new ApplicationInsightsService(process.env.APPLICATION_INSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING)
    }

    public reportEvent(event: Event) {
        this._instance.trackEvent({
            name: event.type,
            properties: event
        })
        this._instance.flush()
    }
}
```

However the events I send are never visible in Azure Portal when I query the `customEvents` table. I've waited for > 10 minutes since I know there can be delays in application insights.

I've tried making the call to flush asynchronous instead and using `await` when calling it, but that doesn't help either:

```js
Promise.resolve(this._instance.flush(true))
```

The environment variable `APPLICATION_INSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING` has the format `InstrumentationKey=xxx;IngestionEndpoint=https://westeurope-1.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/`.

My issue seems very similar to [C# Application Insight Failure: TrackEvent Does not send to Azure Application Insight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52035598/c-sharp-application-insight-failure-trackevent-does-not-send-to-azure-applicati), but do I *really* need to sleep/time out to account for timings?

The log output when I run this says nothing, no errors produced and nothing seems off:

```
[12/17/2020 11:06:10 AM] Executing 'Functions.EventHandler' (Reason='New ServiceBus message detected on 'integrator-events'.', Id=812ccf8f-3cd3-4c75-8ab4-20614556d597)
[12/17/2020 11:06:10 AM] Trigger Details: MessageId: 125f60d79c5a4b029a417bee68df95d7, DeliveryCount: 1, EnqueuedTime: 12/17/2020 11:06:11 AM, LockedUntil: 12/17/2020 11:07:11 AM, SessionId: (null)
[12/17/2020 11:06:10 AM] Received event
[12/17/2020 11:06:10 AM] Successfully sent event to application insights
[12/17/2020 11:06:10 AM] Executed 'Functions.EventHandler' (Succeeded, Id=812ccf8f-3cd3-4c75-8ab4-20614556d597)
```

What am I missing?

*Update*

So apparently there's a [JavaScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/javascript) *and* a [Node](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/nodejs) SDK to make things more confusing. I'll try with the Node SDK, but I don't see why the former shouldn't work.

*Solution*

The following construction of the ApplicationInsightsService works:

```js
// Previously:
// import { ApplicationInsights } from "@microsoft/applicationinsights-web"
import { TelemetryClient } from "applicationinsights"

export class ApplicationInsightsService {

    private _instance: TelemetryClient

    private constructor(connectionString: string) {
        this._instance = new TelemetryClient(connectionString)
    }
}
```

For node applications:

**Do**: `npm install --save applicationinsights`

**Don't**: `npm install --save @microsoft/applicationinsights-web`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following construction of the `ApplicationInsightsService` works:

```js
// Previously:
// import { ApplicationInsights } from "@microsoft/applicationinsights-web"
import { TelemetryClient } from "applicationinsights"

export class ApplicationInsightsService {

    private _instance: TelemetryClient

    private constructor(connectionString: string) {
        this._instance = new TelemetryClient(connectionString)
    }
}
```

For node applications:

**Do**: `npm install --save applicationinsights`

**Don't**: `npm install --save @microsoft/applicationinsights-web`